# How to store a very small float type number in MIPS? (I.e 1x2^-18)

Tags: floating, mips32, exponent, qtspim

I want to store 1.23211e-18 to a float variable. Here is how I would do it for a value that can be written without an exponent:

.data
number: .float 2.43221

But how to do it for a very small value like 1.23211e-18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter 4 of the **MIPS Assembly Language Programmer's Guide** (a web search will find many copies of a PDF of that book if you don't already have a copy) describes the format of floating-point constants.  It says you should be able to write that value exactly as you did in the question:

```
    .float 1.23211e-18
```